error:read in flex scanner failed,using gnu tool chain
I am a beginner in CMake, and I encountered the following error while compiling an STM32 project using the GNU toolchain:
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: read in flex scanner failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Drone.elf.dir/build.make:1151: Drone.elf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/Drone.elf.dir/all] Error 2

And this is my CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Drone NONE)

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# output compile_commands.json
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

#language
enable_language(C ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# add startup file
set(STARTUP_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CORE/startup_stm32f401xe.s)
set(OS_CPU_A_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/os/os_cpu_a.s)

# add .h
set(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CORE/STM32F401RETx_FLASH.ld)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CORE)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FWLIB/inc)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/HARDWARE/inc)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SYSTEM/inc)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/USER/inc)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/os/inc)

# add .c
file(GLOB SOURCE 
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/USER/src/*.c" 
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FWLIB/src/*.c"
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/HARDWARE/src/*.c"
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SYSTEM/src/*.c"
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/os/src/*.c" 
)
set(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE})

# set compiler and linker
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc)                                                        
set(CMAKE_LINKER /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld)

add_definitions(-DSTM32F401xx -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER)

# 设置编译选项
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c99 -g -Os \
    -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra \
    -Wno-self-assign -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-empty-body")
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu++17 -g -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -g -x assembler-with-cpp")

# 设置链接选项
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mcpu=cortex-m4 \
    --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float \
    -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_NAME}.map -T${LINKER_SCRIPT}")

# ${OS_CPU_A_FILE}
# 添加可执行文件
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${SOURCE_FILES} ${STARTUP_FILE} ${OS_CPU_A_FILE})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_NAME}.map -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--print-memory-usage -Wl,-lc -lm)

I have tried to modify my .ld file, and I believe there are no errors in my .ld file. I have also confirmed that all my paths are correct.
I came across an article with an error similar to mine, which originated from: having spaces between commas; and providing an incorrect path for the -T input. I believe I might not have made any mistakes in these aspects.
Could you please tell me what‘s wrong with my Cmake？
I solved my problem throw deleting -T${LINKER_SCRIPT},but I am worry about that if I delete this option,My project might be worng.So I change the whole sentence into
add_link_options(-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -DSTM32F401xx -T${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32F401RETx_FLASH.ld --specs=nano.specs -u _printf_float -lc -lm -Wl,-Map=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections)



The error is definitely about one of the options you are passing to the linker via CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS variable or via parameter to target_link_libraries command. Remove any of those options and check whether the given error disappears. If not, then try to remove some other option.
